# mySQL and PHP to filter $_GET Results from Database

Tags: php, mysql, get

My code receives a brand from an html form, it then proceeds to generate the search results from the database.

```
      if(isset($_GET['brand'])) {
    $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['brand']);
    echo $brand;

    $featuredSql = "SELECT t.*, s.quantity, s.rrp AS nRetailPrice, r.city AS city_name, ts.thumbnail as tread_thumbnail, ts.bigpic as tread_bigpic, t.rating FROM tyres t INNER JOIN stocklevels s 
ON t.stockcode=s.stockcode LEFT JOIN tyre_treads ts ON t.treadid=ts.recid LEFT JOIN reseller r ON s.city=r.recid WHERE s.quantity>0 ";


    if ($brand != 'Any') $featuredSql .= " AND t.manufacturer='$brand'";
    $featuredSql .= "GROUP BY t.diam,t.manufacturer, t.width";
    if (!$featured = mysqli_query($db, $featuredSql)) die(mysqli_error());
    var_dump($featured);
    if (!$tyre1 = mysqli_fetch_object($featured)) echo "<br />No tyres match those parameters. Please try again.";
}
```

The HTML to represent the data once collected.

```
 <div class="text text-background">
 <h4>
     <a href="detail.php"><?= $product["profile"] . "/" . $product["width"] . "/" . $product["diam"] . " " . $product['manufacturer']; ?></a>
 </h4>
     <p class="brand"><a href="#"><?= $product["part_no"]; ?></a></p>
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <div class="txtprice-small">PRICE FROM $<span><?= $product["nRetailPrice"]; ?></span></div>
     </div>
     <table class="table table-condensed small">
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td width="40%">SIZE:</td>
              <td width="60%"><?= $product["diam"]; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Width:</td>
              <td><?= $product["width"]; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Profile:</td>
              <td><?= $product["profile"]; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Stock:</td>
              <td><?= $product["quantity"]; ?></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Rating:</td>
              <td><?= $product["rating"] ?></td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


        if ($brand != 'Any') $featuredSql .= " AND t.manufacturer='$brand'";
        $featuredSql .= "GROUP BY t.diam,t.manufacturer, t.width";
        if (!$featured = mysqli_query($db, $featuredSql)) die(mysqli_error());
        var_dump($featured);
        if (!$tyre1 = mysqli_fetch_object($featured)) echo "<br />No tyres match those parameters. Please try again.";
    }
```

Now the problem is the database is poorly maintained and several items are duplicates (hence the GROUP BY diam, manufacturer and width) but each of those items has its own stock, eg

Item part_no abc stock 5,
Item part_no abc stock 7

so there are actually 12, but are both listed as separate items,the GROUP_BY groups them together, but doesn't do anything with the stock level.

My question is how should I handle this? I've looked at trying to use COUNT in the original Query, but the while loop with the fetch assoc breaks if I do that. Although I could have coded it incorrectly (fairly new to PHP and using MySQL).
I could also GROUP BY part_no but this doesn't seem to help either.

Additional Information as recommended

Tyre's Database
RecID is Unique Primary Key
part_no Not Unique
stockCode IS UNIQUE

Sample Data

```
    \/65\/14-4015","thumbnail":null,"bigpic":null,"rating":"82H","tread":null,"profile":"65","width":"175","diam":"14","description":null,"rrp":"0.00","flag":null,"notes":"","treadid":"707","hide":"no","quantity":"1","nRetailPrice":"79.00","city_name":"New Plymouth","tread_thumbnail":"707_thumb.jpg","tread_bigpic":"707_large.jpg"},

{"recid":"3705","part_no":"ALT185\/65\/14","manufacturer":"ALTENZO","supplier":null,"stockcode":"TY-ALT185\/65\/14-3705","thumbnail":null,"bigpic":null,"rating":"86H","tread":null,"profile":"65","width":"185","diam":"14","description":null,"rrp":"0.00","flag":null,"notes":"","treadid":"707","hide":"no","quantity":"1","nRetailPrice":"79.00","city_name":"Palmerston North","tread_thumbnail":"707_thumb.jpg","tread_bigpic":"707_large.jpg"},

{"recid":"4557","part_no":"ALT185\/60\/15","manufacturer":"Altenzo","supplier":null,"stockcode":"TY-ALT185\/60\/15-4557","thumbnail":null,"bigpic":null,"rating":"88H","tread":null,"profile":"60","width":"185","diam":"15","description":null,"rrp":"0.00","flag":null,"notes":"","treadid":"707","hide":"no","quantity":"2","nRetailPrice":"99.00","city_name":"Petone","tread_thumbnail":"707_thumb.jpg","tread_bigpic":"707_large.jpg"},

{"recid":"2827","part_no":"ALT195\/50\/15","manufacturer":"ALTENZO","supplier":null,"stockcode":"TY-ALT195
```

Comment: No indication given as to whether `stockcode` is *unique* in either `tyres` or `stocklevels`.  Also, it looks like the outer joins to `tyretreads` and/or `resellers` could match multiple rows producing "duplicates". (Again, no indication whether `recid` is unique in either `tyre_treads` or `reseller`.) Without information about uniqueness, and example data and expected output, any "answers" you get are just going to be guesses.